# How can I get firebase notification data?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I can get Firebase message in `onMessage` when i'm in app like this:

```
{data: {}, notification: {body: how are you , title: hi}}
```

My code in `initState`:

```dart
    firebaseMessaging.configure(

    onLaunch: (Map<String,dynamic> msg){
      print(" onLaunch called");
      print(msg);
    },
    onResume: (Map<String,dynamic> msg){
      print(" onResume called");
      print(msg);

    },
    onMessage: (Map<String,dynamic> msg){
      print(" onMessage called");
      print(msg);
      setState(() {
        sms=msg['notification']['body'];
      });
    },


    );
     firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
      const IosNotificationSettings(
          sound: true,
          alert: true,
          badge: true
      )
    );
      firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered.listen((IosNotificationSettings setting){
       print("ios setting registed");
    });
      firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token){
       update(token);
    });
    }
     update(String token){
       print(token);
        setState(() {
         textValue=token;
     });
```

I want to get Firebase message when app in background or closed,
how can I get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to know is describe in the [Receiving Message](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging#receiving-messages) section of the Firebase Messaging package.

Methods `onResume` and `onLaunch` methods are fires **only when the user clicks on the notification**

Comment: im new how can i get get message in onResume ?

Comment: launch your app in debug mode, put it in background (not killed) and send the notification. 

When you click on the notification, the `onResume` method will be triggered.

For Android, the `click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK` need to be present.